# Shift (Complete) Specific Rows Left in R

Tags: r, row, shift

I pulled a data.frame from the internet and need to shift completely, (5 of 168) specific rows to the left one column.  I thought best to append a column to the front of the data.frame and move the rows over but am unsuccessful.  For example, I need something like this:

```
a b c d e    >>>    a b c d e
0 1 2 3 4           0 1 2 3 4
0 0 1 2 3           0 1 2 3 NA
0 1 2 3 4           0 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know which rows you want to shift, you can replace the first value(s) of these rows with NA, and then use `hacksaw::shift_row_values`.

```r
library(hacksaw)
data[2, "a"] <- NA
data %>% 
  shift_row_values(at = 2)

  a b c d  e
1 0 1 2 3  4
2 0 1 2 3 NA
3 0 1 2 3  4
```

---

data

```r
data <- read.table(header = T, text = "
           a b c d e
    0 1 2 3 4 
    0 0 1 2 3     
    0 1 2 3 4 ")
```

Comment: Good to know about the function `shift_row_values`

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, based on base R:

```r
rows <- 2:3

df[rows,] <- cbind(df[rows, -1], NA)

df

#>   a b c d  e
#> 1 0 1 2 3  4
#> 2 0 1 2 3 NA
#> 3 1 2 3 4 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace a row with an offset part plus NA like this:

```
dat[2,] <- c(dat[2, 2:5], NA)
```

Data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="
a b c d e    
0 1 2 3 4           
0 0 1 2 3           
0 1 2 3 4",
header=TRUE)
```